# Integrar Classes da ES2015 com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, babel

Depois de muita leitura eu finalmente consegui fazer a [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) funcionar e, assim, transcompilar os scripts.

Antes de utilizar das, vamos chamar de classes da ES2015, após ler sobre [melhores práticas](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/8) eu tinha algo assim:

```
( function( Navigation, window, document, $, undefined ) {

    Navigation.menu = function() {

        ( '#menu' ).on( 'click wheel', function( e ) {

            // Do something with DOM

        });
    }

    Navigation.menu();

}( window.Navigation = window.Navigation || {}, window, document, window.jQuery ) );
```

Então, aos poucos, eu fui tentando fazer a implementação com a ES2015:

```
class Navigation {

    constructor( data ) {

        this.data = data;

        this.init();
    }
}

class Menu extends Navigation {

    init() {

        $( '#menu' ).on( 'click wheel', function( e ) {

            // Do something with DOM
        });
    }
}
```

Criei uma classe base com aquilo que é comum à cada tipo de navegação (menu, sidebar...) achando que assim que Objeto **Menu** fosse instanciado o construtor de **Navigation** chamaria o método *init*, inicializando o Evento.

Funciona, mas não como eu imaginei.

Dentro de `Navigation.init()` (*Location* na verdade, mas apenas para contextualizar um método abstrato), se eu tentar acessar as propriedades de *Navigation*:

```
console.log( this.data );
```

Funciona perfeitamente como esperado mas dentro de jQuery.on() eu recebo um *undefined* o.O

Eu imaginei que, talvez, o escopo de `this`pudesse estar sendo sobrescrito e depurei apenas ele e obtive o nó clicado (uma imagem).

E eu queria saber o porquê, é claro, mas também como consertar isso para integrar adequadamente, se for possível, mas preferivelmente sem ter que, por exemplo, injetar o escopo `this` em `Navigation.init()`:

```
class Navigation {

    constructor( data ) {

        this.data = data;

        this.init( this );
    }
}

class Menu extends navigation {

    init( _this ) {

        // _this points to Navigation, inside or inside jQuery.on()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pela forma como o jQuery funciona com os callback de eventos, ele faz com que o `this` seja o elemento que disparou o evento.

Como você está usando o Babel então fica bem simples resolver esse problema, é só você usar uma *Arrow Function*, que diferente de uma função, anônima ou não, ela não altera o contexto do `this`, ficaria assim

```
init() {
    $( '#menu' ).on( 'click wheel', ( e ) => {
         // agora aqui o this vai continuar sendo a sua classe
    });
}
```

Repare que tudo que mudou foi a remoção do keyword `function` e a adição da *seta* `=>`.

O Babel vai saber converter isso corretamente, no javascript final ele deve criar uma nova variável temporária automáticamente

O detalhe que fica ai é que uma coisa comum do jQuery é usar `$(this)` para manipular o elemento que disparou o evento, o que não vai mais funcionar, mas você ainda pode pegar o elemento que disparou o evento neste caso pelo `e.target` ou `e.currentTarget`, então poderia também fazer algo como `$(e.target)` para manipular o elemento com o jQuery.

No caso do `e.target` pode acontecer de não ser o mesmo elemento do `this`, isso pode acontecer quando o evento veio de um elemento filho do qual você adicionou o event handler, por exemplo

```
<div id="menu">
    <div>
        teste
    </div>  
</div>
```

Com este HTML se eu adicionar um handler para o click do `$("#menu")` o `e.target` vai me retornar o `div` interno, enquanto o `this` seria o `div` externo, neste caso usando o `e.currentTarget` ele retornaria o mesmo que o `this`.

A documentação não fala muito sobre a diferença entre o `this` e o `e.currentTarget`, mas pesquisando sobre isso encontrei explicações dizendo que no geral seriam os mesmos valores, a menos que fosse usado o `$.proxy` para alterar o contexto da função.

Inclusive devo acrescentar que o `$.proxy` também é uma alternativa para corrigir o seu problema, ficaria assim:

```
init() {
    $( '#menu' ).on( 'click wheel', $.proxy(function( e ) {
         // agora aqui o this vai continuar sendo a sua classe
    }, this));
}
```

Basicamente você passa a função e seu `this` atual, que representa a instância de sua classe, porém ainda acontece a mesma coisa que aconteceria usando uma *Arrow Function*, como o `this` foi modificado não tem como usar o `$(this)`, seria necessário usar `$(e.currentTarget)` por exemplo, então acho a primeira forma mais simples, ficando com o código mais limpo.

Em ultimo caso, se você realmente quiser ou por algum motivo precisar usar `$(this)`, então a alternativa é capturar o `this` em uma variável local

```
init() {
    let _this = this; //ou var _this = this;
    $( '#menu' ).on( 'click wheel', function( e ) {
         // agora aqui você pode usar o _this para acessar sua classe
         // e ainda pode usar o $(this) para manipular o elemento
    });
}
```

Comment: E passar a usar `$( e.target )` ao invés de `$( this )` é seguro, sem problemas de compatibilidade?

Comment: @user5613506 eu diria que na maioria dos casos sim, mas a documentação cita que existem casos em que o `this` e o `e.target` podem não ser o mesmo elemento no caso de ter ocorrido a propagação do evento de algum elemento filho, mas olhando a documentação me parece ser possível usar também o `e.currentTarget`, vou incluir mais algumas informações na resposta